# Text and Button align

Tags: html, css, image

I am a really beginner of css and I was working on my portfolio site but I cannot come out of this problem. So I was wondering if someone could help me out who is more advanced with html/css.
I want on the left and right side a image and on the opposite the text with the button.
Problem: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FlatDesigner/kxy8u/)

I wanna make it look like this:

```
http://larsdejonge.nl/img/werk/work.png
```

Thanks for already looking into this problem.
- Lars

Comment: Please look now I have made some changes http://jsfiddle.net/kxy8u/3/

Comment: I can fix if you can confirm Image size.

Comment: I am new with stackoverflow how do I put the HTML and CSS in the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my version: http://jsfiddle.net/kxy8u/7/

Rewrote your HTML structure, as you could experience UI inconsistency in different browsers. Also removed wrapper around your links (by the way you had repeating `#button` elements, should use class `.` instead).

Also role of `.content__row--container` is to allow you safely add margin or padding to it, otherwise if you apply padding on parent element it will increase it width size and columns won't be at the same line. Instead of that you could use `box-sizing : border-box;` on parent element, but it won't work in IE8 then unless you add polyfill.

Here's how it looks:
[image]

Comment: That's almost perfectly what I tried to do. Could you maybe do 1 thing more if that is even possible? From the bottom line and image do 40px off from the side. So the "See Project buttom" will always be next to the image but than 40px away from it.

Comment: You mean something like that, but with 40px gap between bottom line and image? http://jsfiddle.net/kxy8u/9/

Comment: Yeeh but than just 40px above the line so it is on the bottom if that is possible.

Comment: @FlatDesigners http://jsfiddle.net/kxy8u/10/

Comment: No the /9 was good but I mean can you do the button downwards from the line. Just like the button is flying 40px above the line.

Comment: But is my last comment possible?

Comment: Ed, too bad you aren't getting paid for this, but @FlatDesigners is. Maybe HE should pay you. Or, you know... do some work himself. Good on you for not answering the moving goalpost question Ed.

Answer (score 0):

Please see in below given link it will help you.

```
"http://jsfiddle.net/JDH3E/4"
```

I have updated some css and HTML not completely done because fo second image size you should fix the image size because your parent div with class "leftimage" width is 50% and image is bigger so please fix the image size

Comment: I will make the images smaller for you.

Comment: No i don't need smaller images. Just let me know that all images will be same height width?

Comment: Hello Yogesh I did change the image.

Comment: Please provide me URL where I can see

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kxy8u/3/ < I did edit them and put them on the website so they are smaller now if you refresh the page.

Comment: Please see this http://jsfiddle.net/JDH3E/4/ is this you want

Answer (score 0):

[Js fiddle demo with html](http://jsfiddle.net/rvpatel/kxy8u/6/)

```
I have created html and css code for your structure.
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Basically the problem with your css was that you have given the 50% width to the parent div's and they have taken that width but you haven't restricted the image width i.e. why it was getting mis-aligned.

Also you havenot added text in you fiddle so i also haven't added that.

I have created a fiddle according to your requierents. Please check!

http://jsfiddle.net/JDH3E/1/

```
<body>
        <div id="content">              

            <div class="leftimage">
                <img src="http://larsdejonge.nl/img/werk/foto_2.jpg" alt="fiets"/>
                <div class="left">
                    <div id="button">   
                        <a href="http://www.larsdejonge.nl/project2.html" style="text-decoration: none;">See Project</a>
                    </div>  
                </div>  
            </div>  


            <div class="rightimage">
                <img src="http://larsdejonge.nl/img/werk/foto_1.jpg" alt="fiets"/>

                <div class="left">
                    <div id="button">   
                        <a href="http://www.larsdejonge.nl/project1.html" style="text-decoration: none;">See Project</a>
                    </div> 
                </div>
            </div>



        </div> 
 </body>



            <!-- Wanna make looking like this: http://larsdejonge.nl/img/werk/work.png -->
```

And css goes here:

```
#content{
    width:100%;
    max-width:100%;
}


.leftimage{


    width:50%;
    max-width:50%;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}

.leftimage img{
    width:100%;
    max-width:100%;
}

.rightimage img{
    width:100%;
    max-width:100%;
}

.rightimage{
   width:50%;
    max-width:50%;
    float:right; 
    position:relative;

}


#button {
    margin-top: 30px;
}
#button > a {
    border: 1px solid #99bbd4;
  border-radius: 2px;
    padding: 7px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #99bbd4;
    font-family: 'roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 13px;
    transition: all .2s ease;
}

#button > a:hover {
    background-color: #99bbd4;
    color: #fff;
}

.left{
 position:absolute;
    right:10%;
    top:50%;
}
```

You can definitely alter this as per your requirements.